# The style of the QPushButton be changed after set non-english (Unicode) text

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

A simple dialog and a button are created with the following code:

```
QDialog d;
QPushButton b("Hello", &d);
d.setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
d.show();
```

Result is:

[image]

With translation:

```
QDialog d;
QPushButton b(QObject::tr("Hello"), &d);
d.setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
d.show();
```

Result is:

[image]

Why the style changed?

Update:

1. I realized that this is not a problem with the translation system, this problem occurs whenever non-English text is set to a QPushButton
2. If I use QMainWindow instead QDialog there is no problem.